# gcc: -pthread: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, c, gtk

Trying to compile following code in ***terminal*** i got

`gcc:  -pthread: No such file or directory`,

what does this error means and how to eliminate it?

**file name:** *window.c*

**code:**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL); 
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();
  return 0;

}
```

I tried to compile it with following parameters:-

```
gcc -Wall -g window.c -o window `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Comment: In my case it was solved by re-cloning my git repo then I re-installed deps and it compiled and ran successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It most likely means that your system doesn't have the development portion of the threading library installed. You can find out what thread `-pthread` flag does on your platform with the following command:

`gcc -dumpspecs | grep "%{pthread"`

I get this:

```
%{posix:-D_POSIX_SOURCE} %{pthread:-D_REENTRANT}
%{pthread:-lpthread}    %{shared:-lc}    %{!shared:%{mieee-fp:-lieee} %{profile:-lc_p}%{!profile:-lc}}
```

Which means that `-pthread` on my system adds `-D_REENTRANT` and `-lpthread`. So the missing file would be `libpthread.sometihing`.

Comment: At this point, the terminal compiles fine. But the error message still shows up when i try to compile the source through `Shell Script` or IDEs like `Geany`

Comment: If somebody gets here many years later as it happened to me, I describe my solution. I was getting the same error as the OP when compiling from CLion using a docker container based on ubuntu 18.04 (which comes with `cmake 3.10` in the repositories). The problem really only appeared when using `cmake`, not when using `gcc` with the `-pthread` flag. I just compiled `cmake 3.16` from source and everything worked well